# createFromFormat validation fail

Tags: 8, datetime, migrations

I have migration where I have to migrate date field. Migration has problem with date format. After some debugging I have found that I have problem in method [DateTimePlus::createFromFormat](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Datetime%21DateTimePlus.php/function/DateTimePlus%3A%3AcreateFromFormat/8.3.x)

There is `validate_format` parameter that indicates if validate date format or not. But I can't find out what can I do if validation fails. Validation failure is correct because dates are not same:

```
2016-11-30T00:00:00
2016-12-00T00:00:00
```

Have anybody ever had same problem? Is there anything I can do to fix this?

I have noticed that problem occurs if date field has only defined year and month. For fields with defined year, month and day it seems work correctly.